# Formatting error?

Tags: c, windows

Possibly dumb question - I keep getting this error

```
error: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int (*)(int,  int,  int,  int)'
```

and have no idea what it means. Here is the relevant code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
int dayOfWeek (int doomsday, int leapYear, int month, int day) {

    int doomsday;
    int daysfromdd;
    int month;
    int day;
    int leapYear;
    int date;

    printf ("Insert date");
    scanf ("%d %d %d %d", doomsday, leapYear, month, day);
}
```

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: The error message is not related to the line you posted (which is also buggy by the way).

Comment: Please post more of the code. In the example string you do not use the %d formatter.

Comment: I don't think you are showing enough code. What is `date`?

Comment: Well now that you have changed the example, your error is probably different. My guess is that you're trying to use a struct containing fields doomsday, leapYear, month, and day but don't know how to access them.

Feel free to show more of the code, because it will only help us understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark here, but you probably want to do this `scanf ("%d %d %d %d", &doomsday, &leapYear, &month, &day);` where doomsday, leapYear, month, and day are `int`s. Then pass those to `date`.

Comment: The code you posted has other problems.

Comment: The braces don't match, and it looks as if you are trying to nest a function in `main()`.

Comment: Could you please point them out? edit: forgot a brace, but it's there in the original. Can I not nest functions in main?

Comment: Count them yourself. There are two `{` but only one `}`.

Comment: No. You can't nest functions in C.

Comment: Thank you - sorry for the complete newbie questions, but would fixing the attempted nesting also get rid of the error, or is that another formatting mistake on my part?

Comment: Move your `dayOfWeek` function outside of main and you're also re-declaring the parameters that are passed. It's hard to help when we don't know exactly what your intentions are. Also, is that all of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I can say about your question so far. To use the scanf function, you have to pass the memory address of your variable to it using the & symbol.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dayOfWeek (int doomsday, int leapYear, int month, int day) {
    // what is this supposed to do?
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int doomsday;
    int month;
    int day;
    int leapYear;
    // int date;
    //int daysfromdd;

    printf ("Insert date: ");
    scanf ("%d %d %d %d", &doomsday, &leapYear, &month, &day);

    printf("DD: %d, LY: %d, M: %d, D: %d\n",
            doomsday, leapYear, month, day);

    return 0;
}
```

However I don't know what dayOfTheWeek() is supposed to do since you put no description of it.